# $O_{\pi}(G/N)=PN/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Is the following statement correct?

> Let $\pi$ be a set of primes and let $P$ be a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G'\subseteq N$, then $O_{\pi}(G/N)=PN/N$.

**Proof:** Since $P$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$, so $PN/N$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G/N$. Thus, $O_{\pi}(G/N)\subseteq PN/N$. On the other hand, because $G'\subseteq N$, so $G/N$ is Abelian. In particular, $PN/N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$. As $O_{\pi}(G/N)$ is the largest normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G/N$, it follows that $O_{\pi}(G/N)\supseteq PN/N$, and we're done.

---

If the statement is true, is my *proof* correct and is there a more trivial way to prove this? The reason I doubt this is because if $N\subseteq P$, then $PN=P$. As inverse image of a normal subgroup is also normal, we would obtain that $P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which seems dubious to me.

Comment: If $G'\leqslant P$ then $P$ is indeed normal.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Good point.

Comment: @ancientmathematician So the original statement is correct?

Comment: Yes. I think what you have done is OK.